# Angular 15: Project is not defined in this workspace while adding angular pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular15, angular-pwa

I was adding angular/pwa in my project built in Angular 15 by running the below command,

`ng add @angular/pwa --project <project-name>`

Result,

[image]

What is this error?

Comment: The error signifies command is being run at the wrong path, please check your folder does it contain angular.json?

Comment: Yes, angular.josn was there. But the name of the project was different and changed to `texales` and working as expected. Thanks @Navitas28

Comment: The name is also case sensitive. In my case, the project name was all lowercase in package.json and camel cased in angular.json. It should match angular.json.

Comment: Yes, This is a good point to remember.